# Why `Community` user automagically edits an answer?

Tags: support, editing, community-user

Today, the pseudo `Community` user automagically edited [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170716/14500) (it replaced the `pgfmanual` word by `pgfmanual`!)

Why?

Comment: Related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/what-is-community-up-to-here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a suggested edit by I think a non-registered user. Community gets assigned quite a few of these sort of things: perfectly normal.

Comment: At first glance, the change was to replace a word with the same word which seemed totally unnecessary. But I did not see that the URL of the link had been corrected. The observed behavior is perfectly normal. Thank you.